# Android: UDP client on HTC devices

Tags: android, udp, htc-android

My application contains a client thread (UDP and TCP) which receive data from a wifi interface. I've tested the app on some devices (Samsung, sony, and HTC). It works well on all the devices in TCP mode, but in UDP mode it only works on Sony and Samsung devices, not in HTC.

Here is my UDP code:

```
                socketUDP = new DatagramSocket(SERVERPORT);
                byte[] buf = new byte[50];
                socketUDP.setSoTimeout(timeOut);

                DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);

                while (UDPRunning) {

                    socketUDP.receive(packet);

                    String str = new String(packet.getData(), 0,
                            packet.getLength());
                    packet.setLength(buf.length);

                    Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    b.putString("getStr", str);
                    msg.setData(b);

                    handler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
```

HTC Devices tested : HTC sensation (android 4.0.3), HTC desire (android 2.2), HTC One SV (4.0.4)

My question:
Is there any specific autorisations to use for HTC devices in order to use this UDP client?

Comment: did you try using a different port? maybe it's in use?

Comment: Yes, i've made the same tests on every devices. The port wasn't in use

Comment: I have the same exact issue! I hope we find someway out of it.
please let me know if you come up with something.

Comment: I haven't found any solution yet. I'll tell you if I found something!

Comment: how does it not work well? Exception? packets not received?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my device it was also HTC sensation. It was not reachable by the other side(client) on pc.
May the link will help you sorting it out . I never tried that solution because i changed my phone.

http://www.flattermann.net/2010/09/fix-udp-broadcasts-on-htc-phones-running-stock-firmware/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: I think you are right. But the thing is that i only had an answer in the form of that link.. if that will help them solving their problem then this is the answer. You dont like tha answer ok go ahead and delete it.:)..

Comment: And yes please read the question carefully.. and then look at my answer if you like to then ask yourself. And listen to eminem's survival...